# How to use dialog-modal confirmation before deleting?

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, confirmation

This is the first time I'm use jQuery [dialog_modal confirmation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).
I want to use this before deleting data inside ajax function.
I'm still confused how to put this script correctly.

Before using this dialog I have some script like:

```
 $('#delete').click(function() {
          var params = $('#deletedata').serialize();
          $.ajax({
                   async  : false,
                   cache  : false,
                   data   : params,
                   success: function(res) {
                     //        oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                               $('#recline1').replaceWith("<div id='recline1'></div>");
                               $('#recmodel1').replaceWith("<div id='recmodel1'></div>");
                               $('#tabs').hide();
                               return this;
                               },
                   type   : "POST",
                   url    : "process1.php",
                   });
             return false;
        });
```

I want if `delete` is clicked, this dialog will appear then if we choose `delete at dialog` the deleting process will do, but if we choose `no` all opened tabs and this dialog will hide.

---

#### Edit

I have tried like this, and the dialog confirm can appear:

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
              $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');
              var params = $('#deletedata').serialize();
              ....
```

I am still confused in how to get button id inside modal confirmation then combine with ajax function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your ajax function into the button handler on the dialog initialise.  Then open as you describe above.

```
$('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Delete': function () {
            // Perform the delete
            $.ajax({
                url: "process1.php",
                success: function () {
                    ...
                }
            });
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: arghhhhhh...i miss this part...sorry for my limited knowledge..thanks a lot Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Put two buttons inside your dialog-confirm div, 'Ok' and 'Cancel'

Upon clicking the 'Ok' button, call your ajax code (refactor it to a seperate function) and close the dialog.

Upon clicking the 'Cancel' button, just close the dialog.